# Probability of Selecting 3 Letters from 7 choices

Tags: probability

$A,B,C,D,E,F,G$

A list consists of all possible three-letter arrangements formed by using the letters above such that the first letter is $D$ and one of the remaining letters is $A$. If no letter is used more than once in an arrangement in the list and one three-letter arrangement is randomly selected from the list, what is the probability that the arrangement selected will be $DCA$?

My Attempt:  $1/7 \times 1/6 \times 1/5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt would be right... if the actual question was "what are the chances of choosing DCA out of any random assortment of letters?" But you have to realize that the probability of your question is much higher, since the possibilities have been significantly reduced.

First, since the first letter is a mandatory D, then this question gets reduced to choosing a sequence of two letters out of a choice of six (A,B,C,E,F,G)

Looking at the last two letters, the rest is pretty simple. There are ten possibilities: five with A at the front and each of the remaining five letters at the back, and five of the same in the reverse order. Since "CA" is only one of those ten possibilities, the answer is 1/10.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the first letter is D, we don't have to worry about the first choice.

The second letter has 6 possibilities

If it is A, then the last letter has 5 possibilities

If it is not A (which there are 5 letters that aren't A), then the last letter must be A, so for each of them, there is only one last letter possible

There are 10 ways to meet the requirements

The chance that one that meets the requirements is DCA is 1/10 or 10%

Comment: why not multiply $5 and 6$? i thought picking the letters was mutually exclusive (independent of each other).

Comment: If you dont pick a, there are 5 other letters (6 total, 5 not a)

Comment: The second requirement is that there is an A after the first letter, and although there are 30 (5*6) ways to put two letters after the first letter, only 10 have an A